# jquery select2 plugin how to get only the result 'myString%'

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

i'm using the jquery-select2 plugin but i'm wondering how can i get only results that begins with the typed keyword ( like 'myString%')

Comment: Please provide some sourcecode showing your problem in detail and what you already set up.

Answer (score 11):

The [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#matcher) actually provides an example for that:

```
$("select").select2({
    matcher: function(term, text) {
        return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==0;
    }
});
```

The above matcher is case-insensitive, for case-sensitive remove both `.toUpperCase()` calls.

Comment: now it's work for me, i use : matcher: function(term, text) { return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==1; }

Comment: `indexOf` returns the position in which the term started matching the item's text. `0` is the start of the string while `1` corresponds to the second character of the string (maybe you have some whitespace inside the option's text?). Well glad it worked. `=]`

Comment: you are right Sir, i found a whitespace in the option text as you told me thanks a lot for your help

Comment: To ignore whitespaces you may call `.trim()` before or after `.toUpperCase()` both places.