# Select2 Custom Matcher

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use a custom matcher with the select2 library.  Specifically, I want to return `other` as the not-found option, as well as only match from the beginning of a string.  I found the following to SO questions which answer each of these parts separately:

[Select2, when no option matches, "other" should appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950117/select2-when-no-option-matches-other-should-appear)

and

[jquery select2 plugin how to get only the result 'myString%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809594/jquery-select2-plugin-how-to-get-only-the-result-mystring)

However, when I combine the two techniques, it is no longer matching properly.  My solution looks like:

```
$("#myForm").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    width: width,
    matcher: function(term, text) {
        // THIS IS WHERE I COMBINE THE METHODS
        return text === 'Other' || text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==0;
    },
    sortResults: function(results) {
        if (results.length > 1) results.pop();
            return results;
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong, and what is the proper way to make this matcher function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I accomplished this using regular expressions and by splitting the conditional `||` into two steps.  Final code was:

```
$("#myForm").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    width: width,
    matcher: function(term, text) {
        var terms = term.split(" ");
        for (var i=0; i < terms.length; i++){
            var tester = new RegExp("\\b" + terms[i], 'i');
            if (tester.test(text) == false){
                return (text === 'Other')
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
    sortResults: function(results) {
        if (results.length > 1) {
            results.pop();
        }
        return results;
    },
});
```